# Why am I featured as a New contributor?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, user-accounts, new-users

I have joined this community 2 years and 7 months ago:

[image: Date when I joined Workplace SE]

My first [Reputation Points](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/68449/goncalo-peres-supports-monica?tab=reputation) were earned in 17th October 2018 (through some Edits):
[image: My first reputation points]

My [First Answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/147709/68449) in this community was last week, on 7th November 2019:
[image: My first answer]

Even though my background in this community dates back more than 2 year, my first reputation points were earned over 1 year ago and my first answer was given 4 days ago, **why am I featured as *"New contributor"*?**

[image: New contributor]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's because those previous contributions were edits and not posts in their own right.

See the Main Meta article here:
[Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator)

> **The new indicator works by the age of a user's first visible post.**
>
> Folks will see an indicator when they go to interact with new contributors (visible for a week following their first post) letting them know that the person is new. A handy link to our Code of Conduct will be in the notification for reference.
>
> This could be a question or answer, and the association bonus won't influence the behavior. While you might not be new to our engine, everyone is new when they first join a new community, so the indicator is shown.

As to why you're seeing this on this site after you've been active on other sites and you presumably know how SE works is subtle.

I think the reasoning is that each site has the capability of having a different personality and have different standards of what's an "acceptable" question or answer - so me jumping into SO and asking a programming question that doesn't have the right amount of background information or context will result in my question being heavily downvoted.  The "Black Hand of Welcoming" indicates to other people that I've not posted there before and I might need educating rather than just getting slapped down.

However, I do agree that it can seem somewhat condescending to wear this badge when you're a seasoned pro on other sites.

Your first proper answer was on the 7th, so you need to wear the hand until the 14th.

Comment: Thank you @Snow. If the goal is making the site more welcoming, wouldn't be easier to promote the policy of being nice to everybody? This seems to give space to rudeness with users that are not new - but this is just my 2¢.

Comment: @GoncaloPeressupportsMonica - "wouldn't be easier to promote the policy of being nice to everybody? " - that's been done, too.

Comment: @GoncaloPeressupportsMonica I don't see how saying someone is a "new contributor" can be rude or hurt someone's feelings... It's a notification asking users to be more kind and respectful towards users that, perhaps, don't know their ways on the site perfectly... why do you feel it is rude? Both new and "old" contributors can help others regardless of their time on the site...

Comment: @DarkCygnus I didn't say it's rude. I said that by having this tag in order to foment a better treatment to "New Contributors" it gives space to treat worst users that don't have the tag. Just found a nice [analogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314598/362304) that reflects what I am saying.

Comment: I see, now I get your point better

Comment: And the really weird thing is that, even after you have thousands of rep on the main site, the first time you ask or answer a question on the meta of the site you are again branded a new contributor on the meta. A little weird, but it goes away...

Comment: @JonCuster indeed. The counting starts from the moment that one shares a post (question/answer) on a new environment. And they consider each community a separate environment and each community is, basically, two different environments: meta and main site.

Comment: Is it only me or others too still seeing the indicator live on 18th? (Whereas it should be gone by 15th..)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Main and meta are treated as separate sites and this question was the OP's first meta post so they wear the NC tag on meta until later on today. It looks to already have gone on main.